# Can you use a powershell script to find all shares on servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I just want to know all shares on a server, or better all shares in the domain.  I was hoping it was possible through a powershell script.

Comment: 5600 views cannot be off topic.

Comment: There's also `net view`; which works if dealing with shares on non-Windows machines.  More here: https://superuser.com/a/769694/156700

Answer (score 3):

If you want to inventorize the shares from all computers in a domain, you could use `Get-WmiObject` to query the `Win32_Share` wmi class on each computer:

```
# Import the AD module to the session
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
# Retrieve the dNSHostName attribute from all computer accounts in AD
$ComputerNames = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties dNSHostName |Select-Object -ExpandProperty dNSHostName

$AllComputerShares = @()

foreach($Computer in $ComputerNames)
{
    try{
        $Shares = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_Share -ErrorAction Stop
        $AllComputerShares += $Shares
    }
    catch{
        Write-Error "Failed to connect retrieve Shares from $Computer"
    }
}

# Select the computername and the name, path and comment of the share and Export
$AllComputerShares |Select-Object -Property PSComputerName,Name,Path,Description |Export-Csv -Path C:\Where\Ever\You\Like.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Computer is an Object you should use DNSHostName property

Comment: @SimonOzturk Already doing so, notice `|Select-Object -ExpandProperty dNSHostName`

Comment: i'm getting a list of AD machines and an error that the Object feeded in Select-Object is null

Answer (score 2):

With PowerShell you can use [`Get-SMBShare`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635704.aspx).

If you have OS versions that aren't compatible with this cmdlet, you can use good old [`net share`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490712.aspx) instead.

As for how to run it on each server, you can use [`Invoke-Command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) in PowerShell, or [`psexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from Sysinternals in a command prompt.